# Dynamically insert date into App.Config

Tags: c#, date, app-config, filenames

I have a console based application which pulls files from a database and outputs them onto the C drive. It also outputs an excel file with the details of all outputted files. Here is the snippet of code from the app.config file.

```
  <target name="Group1" acceptedFileTypes="pdf">
    <ftpSettings server="localhost" username="anonymous" password="user@user.com" />
    <metadataEncoder name="Group1" fileName="Group1_YYYYMMDD.xls" />
  </target>
```

Ideally, when the program runs, I would like the excel file to be named with the date appended onto the end of it. Is there any way I can achieve this in the app.config file?

Also, here is the class that relating to the above app.config snippet:

```
public class MetadataEncoderElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    private static readonly ConfigurationProperty messageName = new ConfigurationProperty("name", typeof(string), string.Empty, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsRequired);
    private static readonly ConfigurationProperty fileName = new ConfigurationProperty("fileName", typeof(string), string.Empty, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsRequired);

    public MetadataEncoderElement()
    {
        this.Properties.Add(messageName);
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name { get { return (string)this[messageName]; } }

    [ConfigurationProperty("fileName", IsRequired = true)]
    public string FileName { get { return (string)this[fileName]; } }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys.

**EDIT**

Have edited my code to the following

```
[ConfigurationProperty("fileName", IsRequired = true)]
public string FileName = string.Format(MetadataEncoderElement.fileName, DateTime.Now);
```

However now I have the following errors:

> The best overloaded method match
>   for'string.Format(System.IFormatProvider,
>   string, params object[])' has some
>   invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from'System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty'
>        to 'System.IFormatProvider'
>
> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly improved version of Richards answer:

```
<metadataEncoder name="Group1" fileName="Group1_{0:yyyyMMdd}.xls" />
```

in the code

```
string fileName = string.Format(yourconfig.FileName,DateTime.Now);
```

EDIT:
If you want to build it in your Property you can do it this way:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("fileName", IsRequired = true)]
public string FileName { get { return string.Format((string)this[fileName], DateTime.Now); } }
```

Comment: sorry, I'm fairly new to this so I think I need a bit of handholding sometimes ;-) Where is says yourconfig, what should I put in there? Sorry if that seems like a silly question :-\

Comment: yourconfig should be an instance of MetadataEncoderElement. The way you normally whould access your FileName and Name properties.

Comment: I thought that originally so I tried it, but I got errors so I thought it wasn't right. I've changed the code however I have three errors. I'll modify my post with the errors.

Comment: Post modified. Thanks for your replies so far :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<metadataEncoder name="Group1" fileName="Group1_{0:yyyyMMdd}.xls" />
```

Then do

```
string fileName = String.Format(yourconfig.FileName,DateTime.Now));
```

**EDIT**

You can keep your fileName property as is and create a new property

```
public string CurrentFileName { get { String.Format(this.FileName,DateTime.Now); } }
```

Comment: It would be more flexible to use fileName="Group1_{0:yyyyMMdd}" and then String.Format(yourconfig.FileName, DateTime.Now)

Comment: I did think if thats possible, wasnt sure if it would work though, i stand corrected.

Comment: sorry, I'm fairly new to this so I think I need a bit of handholding sometimes ;-) Where is says yourconfig, what should I put in there? Sorry if that seems like a silly question :-\

Comment: You can keep your filename property in tact and simply add another property that returns the formatted string, i have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me..

```
        public class MetadataEncoderElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("fileName", IsRequired = true)]
        public String FileName
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format((String)this["fileName"], DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
    }
```